# OriginX/Y in ShapeRenderer

Tags: methods, libgdx, shapes

I couldn't find any detailed documentation to the method rect in ShapeRenderer in LibGDX.

```
ShapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height, originX, originY, rotation)
```

Most of the arguments are obvious, but putting anything into originX/Y ends up with the same result.

So, what does originX/Y actually do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It determines around which point the rotation will occur.

Comment: So if I'd set the width and height to 100 and originX/Y to 50, the rotate point would be in center?

Comment: Yes, it will be in the center.